# How do I search a list that is located in a class?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am making a program that can take and store "tweets" into a list. I need to search for the author or a word in the tweet then print both author and all tweets found with search word.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__tweet_r = []

def add_tweet_r(self, recent_tweet):
    self.__tweet_r.append(recent_tweet)
```

This is my list.
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question asks about searching "a list that is located in a class", the two methods you provide show that this doesn't correctly describe the situation: the list is stored not in the class but rather in an instance of the class. In fact, each instance of the class will have its own list.

You haven't said how "tweets" are represented, but your requirements indicate you need access to both the author and body independently. So I'll assume that a tweet is a tuple (author, body).

Let's call the class `C`, containing your two methods and a new one, `search_tweets`:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__tweet_r = []

    def add_tweet_r(self, recent_tweet):
        self.__tweet_r.append(recent_tweet)

    # Add this:
    def search_tweets(self, author=None, string=''):
        """Return a list of all tweets by author (if provided) and containing string."""
        return [ tweet for tweet in self.__tweet_r 
                 if (not author or author == tweet[0]) 
                    and string in tweet[1] ]
```

Because "tweets" are stored in instances of `C`, first we'll create one, and then create some "tweets".

```
c = C()
c.add_tweet_r(('Mike', "Hi"))
c.add_tweet_r(('Joe', "Like Mike said, Hi."))
c.add_tweet_r(('Mike', "I'd gladly say it again, Hi"))
c.add_tweet_r(('Nancy', "Hip-hop extravaganza tonight 9pm at The Firetrap!"))
c.add_tweet_r(('Clem', "Yo."))
```

Now let's take `search_tweets` for a spin:

```
import pprint
lst = c.search_tweets(author='Nancy')
pprint.pprint(lst)
lst = c.search_tweets(author='Mike', string="gladly")
pprint.pprint(lst)
lst = c.search_tweets(string="Hi")
pprint.pprint(lst)
# All tweets
lst = c.search_tweets()
pprint.pprint(lst)
```

Those four searches print the following:

```
[('Nancy', 'Hip-hop extravaganza tonight 9pm at The Firetrap!')]
[('Mike', "I'd gladly say it again, Hi")]
[('Mike', 'Hi'),
 ('Joe', 'Like Mike said, Hi.'),
 ('Mike', "I'd gladly say it again, Hi"),
 ('Nancy', 'Hip-hop extravaganza tonight 9pm at The Firetrap!')]
[('Mike', 'Hi'),
 ('Joe', 'Like Mike said, Hi.'),
 ('Mike', "I'd gladly say it again, Hi"),
 ('Nancy', 'Hip-hop extravaganza tonight 9pm at The Firetrap!'),
 ('Clem', 'Yo.')]
```

The "search for word" part of `search_tweets` is naive - notice that "Hip-hop" matches "Hi". You'll probably want to replace the simple `string in tweet[1]` test with something more sophisticated like a regular expression. But this should get you started.

Comment: recent_tweet = Tweet.Tweet(name_author, Tweet_text, track_time)

store.add_tweet_r(recent_tweet)

This is how I am storing my tweets. I don't know if that will change your answer any.

Comment: Only to the extent that accessing author name and tweet text will be different. What package or module is Tweet? It contains a class (or namedtuple or something) also named `Tweet`. If that class or whatever has attributes `author_name` and `tweet_text`, then, in `search_tweets`, replace `tweet[0]` with `tweet.author_name` and `tweet[1]` with `tweet.tweet_text`.

Comment: You'll also have to adapt the illustration code so that it uses the code in your reply to create actual `Tweet`s rather than my mock tuples, and so that it prints results reasonably. That should be straightforward.

Comment: PS Feel free to indicate that this was the correct answer to your question ;/

Comment: I am still unable to get it to work. When I call for the print of lst i get []. Here is the code.
    def search_tweets(self, author=None, string=''):
        return [ tweet for tweet in self.__tweet_r
                 if (not author or author == tweet.get_author)
                     and string in tweet.get_text]

Comment: Get it to work now but for some reason this is all its returning every time. [<Tweet.Tweet object at 0x02D71A70>]

Comment: That's the print representation of the `tweet`s in the list you get back. Instead of returning `[tweet for tweet in self.__tweet_r ...]` you'll have to return *something like* ``[(tweet.get_author, tweet.get_text) for tweet in self.__tweet_r ...]`. Assuming those attribute names `get_text` and `get_text` are correct.

BUT, what is this Tweet library you're using? (Sorry, I don't know it.) Print out `self.__tweet_r` to be sure that it really contains things that will match your queries.